# Support ADFS on desktop and mobile app

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

We need to build a desktop (using angular4) and a mobile application  (using react-native) that supports single sign on for our clients who are using ADFS in their organisations. We are looking forward to implement outh2 authentication on desktop and mobile app.

Can someone please guide how can we implement it. Should the app(s) be registered at azure-portal or apps.dev.microsoft.com? Do we need a backend API, what would this backend api do?

Thanks.

Comment: There are currently no Angular4 or React-Native samples. There is a SPA sample with plain javascript https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi.

Answer (score 1):

You need to register your app on azure.portal if you want to support sign in with Active Directory organizational or work accounts, which I believe is your case.
The apps.dev.microsoft.com portal is for registering apps that want to support sign in with both AD work accounts and Microsoft personal accounts.

You can read [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#application-types-and-scenarios) to get an idea of the different application types and platforms that are supported.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have a gone through few posts (including above) and have a general idea of how to do sign into our  **own** AD work accounts.  But I am trying to figure out an overview **or** workflow of how to cater Azure AD SSO for our clients who are currently using ADFS in their organisation. For instance how who would we collaborate with client's AD via azure, what configs they or we require on either side to implement the solution.